More efficient image composite with opacity?
 I need to composite a soft light layer on top of a base image using 50% opacity. The following works, but is there a faster or more efficient way to achieve the same thing?
magick base.tif -alpha Off -compose SoftLight softlight.tif -composite fullSoftLightComp.tif
magick base.tif fullSoftLightComp.tif -compose dissolve -define compose:args=50,100 -composite compHalfLight.tif


With Imagemagick, you could try on unix-like systems
magick base.tif -alpha off ( softlight.tif -evaluate multiply 0.5 ) -compose softlight -composite compHalfLight.tif

on Windows remove the \ from before the parentheses, so
Does that do what you want?  Probably not, since you are doing 2 composites.
You could try adjusting the 0.5 fraction to match.

Awesome! Thank you so much. Note that I just needed to escape the parentheses like: \(

I just wanted to say too, that ImageMagick and Fred are legendary. Thank you!

I had that originally. Then I edited my post, but accidentally deleted the Unix equivalent of the Windows command.  Sorry about that. Is that command what you really wanted (as it does not do the same as what you posted)?

I just used it on a test image so far. But it seems to allow adjusting how strong the composited layer which is what I ultimately need. Sounds like I may need to tweak my production settings to get the same results I was. The idea was it applied a full strength composite then used half the opacity of that composite over the original (for this example).

Absolutely no problem about the escapes; I only mentioned it in case it helps someone else.
